# Set of Keys from a Storage Map

Tags: storage

Is it possible to get the set of keys from a Storage Map on Substrate. It doesn’t seem like Substrate exposes a method to do so: https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/storage/trait.StorageMap.html#required-methods.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The FRAME `StorageMap` also implements [`IterableStorageMap`](https://docs.substrate.io/rustdocs/latest/frame_support/storage/trait.IterableStorageMap.html) which allows you to iterate over the keys and/or values of the map:

```
pub trait IterableStorageMap<K: FullEncode, V: FullCodec>: StorageMap<K, V> {
    type Iterator: Iterator<Item = (K, V)>;
    type KeyIterator: Iterator<Item = K>;
    fn iter() -> Self::Iterator;
    fn iter_from(starting_raw_key: Vec<u8>) -> Self::Iterator;
    fn iter_keys() -> Self::KeyIterator;
    fn iter_keys_from(starting_raw_key: Vec<u8>) -> Self::KeyIterator;
    fn drain() -> Self::Iterator;
    fn translate<O: Decode, F: FnMut(K, O) -> Option<V>>(f: F);
}
```

However, you should probably never use this in your runtime in an unbounded way. Iterating over the N keys of your storage map would require N database reads, which can be extremely expensive for your runtime weight.

Instead you should use something like `fn iter_keys_from` where you can pick a specific key to start iterating from, and control how many keys you iterate in a single call.

Comment: If I use `fn iter_keys_from` for a non-dynamic `StorageMap` this seems great. But if I add additional keys, then I can't be sure that I miss some keys which were inserted before `iter_keys_from(starting_raw_key)`, right? Example, where assert fails: https://github.com/zeitgeistpm/zeitgeist/blob/f81d03da05f1c3ab75b27af6964594df2dfee6d8/zrml/court/src/tests.rs#L429-L473